# When I should use RDD instead of Dataset in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, rdd

I know that I should use Spark Datasets primarily, however I am wondering if there are good situations where I should use `RDD`s instead of Datasets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a common Spark application you should go for the Dataset/Dataframe. Spark internally optimize those structure and they provide you high level APIs to manipulate the data. However there are situation when RDD are handy:

- When manipulating graphs using GraphX
- When integration with 3rd party libraries that only know how to handle RDD
- When you want to use low level API to have a better control over your workflow (e.g `reduceByKey`, `aggregateByKey`)